# express download pdf to client machine from amazon s3 bucket

Tags: express, pdf, amazon-s3, download

From the client, I make a request to my server. I want my server to receive that request, get the file from s3 using aws-sdk, and then download the pdf to the client's machine.
I've tried doing getObject().createReadStream().pipe(res). I've tried setting Content-Disposition to attachment. I just can't get it to download. I'm wondering if it's a problem on the client, but I'm pretty sure you can do this entirely from the server.

What I need to know is what to do with res after s3.getObject() in order to download a pdf onto the client's machine.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Use s3.getSignedUrl() instead and send that back to the client and open the link in browser